# Is it possible to automatically redirect the download of a file to a container in case the file contain a malware?

Tags: security, containers, malware, phishing

I was wondering if there is an existing tool that can automatically redirect the download of a file to a container ? Or if there is an existing open-source project about it.

For more context, I wanted to know more about the possibility to protect a system from a malware by creating or opening a container, then open or execute the file in it, each time I try to download a suspicious file from the web. Then take differents actions depending on if it's a safe file or not (transfer it from the container to the local system or delete the container)

So if it hasn't been done I would like to understand why. Maybe it's counterproductive or maybe better tools already exists.

Thanks in advance for the response. I hope I have been clear, English isn't my first language.

I haven't try it yet, just want more informations about the idea.

Comment: I believe the key word you are searching for is sandboxing. Trying to open the file in some supervised environment to find out if it tries to do something malicious. I believe some anti-virus software products may have such things already. The greatest drawback of such tools is CPU, memory and time-usage. It is usually sufficient to postpone any malicious actions like 10 seconds after the file is opened, to bypass such mechanisms. Feel free to google for more.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski Okay thank you very much I'm gonna do some more research

Answer (score 0):

You can run a container in interactive mode, and that will provide a sort of sandbox environment for you. However, **make sure you don't mount any volumes into the container.**

For example, if you have a container named `container`, you can run:

```bash
docker run -it container
```

and it will run the container in interactive mode, entering at the entry point specified in the docker build file. You should then be able to mess around and not have to worry about malware, and do some sleuthing.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought, thank you.
But I actually wonder two things :

- What are some interesting vulnerabilities of containers I should look more into ? I already know I have to check the image, the network and configurations errors. I would like to go further if you have other ideas I haven't found yet. 

- And then, I know virus hide their traces, I'm just starting in CS so I don't know exactly what are the popular options for this, do they just clear all logs ? So what should I check if ever the virus isn't "actively active" but may do thing I don't see or hide a process ?

Thx!